# Tab automatically changed when updating @EnvironmentObject property

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

I have a `@StateObject var workoutManager = WorkoutManager()` inside the main struct of the project and I am using it as an `@EnvironmentObject` inside all subviews.

Inside this `WorkoutManager` class I have an array of Workout data type, `[Workout]` with some methods to handle all the operations (add workout, remove, etc).

This `@EnvironmentObject` is present inside all tabs/subvies of a `TabView` and the content of all these tabs is updating based the above `[Workout]` array.
Whenever I change the content of that `[Workout]` array (this is my thinking), the tab automatically changes from the current active tab to the 1st one which is Home in my case.

Here is some code.

`HomeTabView` is the first tab of a TabView while `WorkoutTabView` is the third tab in my app.
While long pressing on `WorkoutCardView` (which for now only displays workout title) and selecting **Delete Workout** button, the selected workout gets deleted and the tab switches to `HomeTabView`. I think this is because in `HomeTabView` I have the `TodayWorkoutsView` which is displaying something based on [Workout] array. I want the current active tab to not change at all.

```
struct HomeTabView: View {  
    @EnvironmentObject var workoutManager: WorkoutManager
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 10, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                    Section {
                        [...]
                        TodayWorkoutsView()
                    } header: {
                        HeaderView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TodayWorkoutsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var workoutManager: WorkoutManager
    @EnvironmentObject var dateModel: DateModel
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack {
            if let workouts = workoutManager.getWorkouts(for: dateModel.extractDate(date: dateModel.currentDay, format: "dd/MM/yyy")) {
                ForEach(workouts) { workout in
                    Text("\(workout.title)")
                }
            } else {
                Text("No workouts assigned.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct WorkoutTabView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var workoutManager: WorkoutManager
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                let workouts = workoutManager.getAllWorkoutsFromCollection()
                if workouts.count > 0 {
                    ForEach(workouts) { workout in
                        WorkoutCardView(workout: workout)
                            .contextMenu {  
                                Button(role: .destructive) {
                                    workoutManager.removeWorkoutFromCollection(workout)
                                } label: {
                                    Label("Delete Workout", systemImage: "trash")
                                }
                            }
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("No workouts found.")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Workouts")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the important parat of `WorkoutManager`:

```
class WorkoutManager: ObservableObject {
   @Published var workouts: [Workout]

   func removeWorkoutFromCollection(_ workout: Workout) {
      workouts.removeAll(where: { $0.id == workout.id } )
   }
}
```

Any idea/tips on how to store that array in order to have full access to change its content from whatever tab I want but without this tab switch to happen?

Comment: It's hard to imagine, without a little bit of code, what can trigger the issue. Try posting a sample code according to these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: your code does not compile or run, there are too many missing parts, specifically `WorkoutManager`. Show a minimum reproducible code that shows your issue.

Comment: Entire code here - https://github.com/zissinasuc/FitnessApp/tree/master/FitnessApp. I think it is easier this way.